# oh my zsh terminal shows weird characters

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I've followed the official git repository of oh my zsh. I've even set the ZSH_THEME = agnoster. But I've been facing some issues in the terminal like the screenshot below.

[image]

Whereas the official documentation shows a picture of the terminal like this.

[image]

I'm using Windows 10, enabled Linux Sub System and installed Ubuntu from Microsoft Store. The terminal I'm seeing on my screen doesn't look even remotely close to the terminal in the documentation, though I've followed all the steps correctly.

Comment: You need a special font (or a specially patched font) to display the characters shown in the documentation. This is noted in https://github.com/agnoster/agnoster-zsh-theme/blob/master/README.md.